# MYSQL Trigger, is it possible to loop once and then disable field update?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, triggers

I have a table called `char` and a column on that table called `guild_id`

I want to make it so that when a field in that column is updated **once** (default is 0, so from 0 to another number) it never allows it to be updated again either through a query_sql() or whatever way the application I am using is doing it in the source. Is this possible?

I have some logic here but I do not know the syntax -

```
CREATE TRIGGER guildcheck 
BEFORE UPDATE ON guild_id
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if(guild_id != 0) THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Player is already in a guild';
END IF;
END;
```

[image]

Also, am I saving the trigger in the right location for MYSQL Workbench? When I run the lightning it saves somewhere?

Comment: Allowing an update once on a table . . . seems really strange.  What is your use-case?

Comment: In my application I have a script that updates the field and it saves in the MYSQL workbench but when I close out of the application the table then defaults back to 0 because the applications send an update query when it closes. The query I do in that script works, I see it change in the table but the application doesn't accept the update when it is running. When the application is restarted/closed and I manually put it in the number in the table it works.

Comment: I would start with null instead of 0, and then only update where column is null

Comment: Note that int is a reserved word in MySQL